# How to strip debug symbols for real in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, macos, strip, micro-optimization, debug-symbols

I have included the following in an Xcode Application project:

```
void very_specific_symbol_that_will_never_appear_by_accident(void) {

}
```

I proceeded to disable all *'debug symbol'* related settings and enable all *'strip'* related settings I could find, for both Debug and Release, including:

- Strip Debug Symbols During Copy (Yes)
- Generate Debug Symbols (No)
- Reflection Metadata Level (None)
- Optimization Level (Fastest, Smallest [-Os])

## The Problem

If I go to Products, find the application, Show Package Contents, and find the executable in MacOS, and then use the `cat` command or view with a text editor, I can still find `very_specific_symbol_that_will_never_appear_by_accident` in the executable file.

If all the symbols were being properly stripped, the function name would not appear in the executable file. The example was not declared `static` so the optimizer would not remove the function, but I can even see the names of `static` symbols in the executable of similar projects.

How can I strip symbols **for real** in a MacOS application in Xcode, so function/global/static names will not appear in the resulting executable?

In case it matters I am using Xcode 11.0 and MacOS 10.15.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to enable `Deployment Postprocessing` in your build settings.

Also, make sure to build in release mode (you can change that by editing your scheme if needed).

**EDIT**

Symbols may not be stripped in debug mode because of other build settings, like `Enable Testability`.
You can change them, although I don't really see the point of stripping symbols on a debug build.

Comment: It worked. However, I do find it strange and mildly aggravating that even if I tell Xcode to strip, enable postprocessing, etc., it will only listen if I put it on Release mode, even if I enable the settings for both Debug and Release.

Comment: Why do you want to strip symbols on a debug build?

Comment: I wouldn't; but it still causes more confusion than good to ignore instructions because it would not make sense.